# Why does my "Request for Permission" screen look like this?

Tags: facebook, permissions

I have an app that requests permission to access certain info from the user's profile. However, when they first visit the app they are asked to login. The problem is they are already logged in to Facebook.

I've tried other apps and they don't make you login first, they just immediately ask permission.

[image: The login screen..]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook authorization message appears differently](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8115225/facebook-authorization-message-appears-differently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in the Facebook Developers Blog post : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/578/

This is the new App Authentification design.

Comment: Oh wow... ok so this is good news for me. Thought I had something screwed up! Thanks so much!